# Change module - one click to toggle button vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, toggle

I have the following code in a module in Excel, however i'd like to assign it to a toggle button.

```
Sub Weeks3Hide()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Hoist Hours")

wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 14 To wsLR
    'analyze date, see if it's 3 weeks or older
    If ws.Cells(x, 7) <= Date - 21 Then
        'hide
        ws.Range("a" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

I've so far got this:  However there is an error in it.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton4_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Hoist Hours")

WsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
If ToggleButton4.Value = True Then
For x = 14 To WsLR
    'analyze date, see if it's 3 weeks or older
    If ws.Cells(x, 7) <= Date - 21 Then
        'hide
        ws.Range("a" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next x
Else
  ws.Range(WsLR).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help!  Thanks in advance

Comment: "there is an error in it" doesn't tell us much about the problem you're having with your code.  Exactly what error do you see?

Comment: Maybe `ws.Range("A14:A" & WsLR).EntireRow.Hidden = False`

Answer (score 1):

This line `ws.Range(WsLR).EntireRow.Hidden = False`.

You cannot refer to range simply with a number.  If you are trying to hide a row you can use `ws.Rows(WsLR).EntireRow.Hidden = False` or something like `ws.Rows("A2:A" & WsLR).EntireRow.Hidden = False`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is unhide any hidden rows. I would then iterate over the cells and use Union to create a Range of target Rows.  In this way, you can hide all the Rows at once.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton4_Click()
    Dim cell As Range, Rows As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Hoist Hours")
        For Each cell In .Range(Cells(14, 7), .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))
            .Rows.Hidden = False
            If Not .ToggleButton1.Value Then Exit Sub

            If cell.Value <= Date - 21 Then
                If Rows Is Nothing Then
                    Set Rows = cell.EntireRow
                Else
                    Set Rows = Union(Rows, cell.EntireRow)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Rows.Hidden = False
    End With

End Sub
```